# Log rotate daily time for specific application

Tags: cron, logrotate

I know that similar question has been already asked, but there was something I am missing:
Is there any option to specify the hour of rotating the logs, **but only for one application** ?

I know that there is a global option to run `/etc/cron.daily` in `/etc/crontab` but I do not want to change the logrotate time for the whole system, but only for one app.

Please help :)

Comment: See `/etc/logrotate.d`. Here is an example: http://linuxconfig.org/logrotate

Comment: You can run a `logrotate` instance specifically for that application.